# Android - Text size the same across all screen sizes

Tags: android, textview

In my Android app I have the following layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/difficultyCardView"
        app:layout_widthPercent="60%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/noHighScoresCardView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pushpin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/diffNameTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="FÁCIL"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In my Nexus 5, setting the text size to 20sp as shown above, makes text occupy, approximately, 75% of CardView's width. The problem is that, when I test this on a smaller phone, it adds ellipsis to the text.

What I want to achieve is that, on EVERY screen size and resolution, the text will exactly occupy 75% of the card with.

So, how can I solve this problem, creating multiple scale folders (ldpi, mdpi, ...) and adjusting font size in each of them, calculating it via code as a percentage, or any other solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the card width on the specific device and multiply by .75, then set the text size to that value.

Answer (score 0):

if you want textview to take 75% of cardview with textsize 20sp then text will spilt into multiple lines.

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
```

remove these properties there is no need and allow textview for multiline

Answer (score 0):

Will the text always be the same? If so the solution is pretty simple.

```
int ratio = 15;
int width = difficultyCardView.getWidth();
diffNameTv.setTextSize(width/ratio);
```

Adjust the ratio till the size is where you want it, then the text will be the same relative size compared to the card no matter what the screen size is.

Comment: My app is localized on both spanish and english, so text won't always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create a responsive layout. To do so create additional layout folders in the res directory. Add the pixel density name at the end of the folder name, separating the text "layout" and the density using a dash (e.g. layout-hdpi, layout-mhdpi, layout-xhdpi etc.) Within these folders, create the layout you want for each density. You can then resize the textview to 75% of each of the different screen sizes based on the pixel density. Therefore if 20sp fills 75% of the hdpi layout then you might need to increase the text size for a the mhdpi to fill 75% of the card.

Android will automatically select the correct layout for a particular device based on the screen size.